# About implementing photo favorites heart button in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm a new to develope App with Swift.

I want to ask you guys how to implement something like favorite heart button that is same thing in the photo app.

(When you click the heart button, that photo goes into the 'Favorites' album.)

I've been looking for it thousands time on internet.

I couldn't find out.

Please help me and thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do ? Are you developing an app in which you are importing iOS photos and want to be able to tag them as favorites ? Do you want to be able to mark a photo as favorite inside iOS Photos app from your own app ?

Comment: I want to be able to mark a photo(which is imported from iOS photos) as favorites inside iOS photos app from my own app.

Comment: @최정일 Please edit your question to better explain exactly what you're after from your comment, and what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html) on `PHAssetChangeRequest`, assuming you have a `PHAsset`, you can mark it as a favorite by making a change request and modifying its `favorite` property. For example:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: asset)
    request.favorite = true
}, completionHandler: { success, error in
    //finished
})
```